# Disappearing action Bar in a Dialog Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-alertdialog

I am using an activity to work as a dialog box. However, the actionBar on the dialog activity is not disappearing. I have tried using:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);

}
```

It Doesn't work. I also set the theme of the app (from the manifest) to be as following:

```
<activity
        android:name=".DialogActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dialog"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert" >
    </activity>
```

Following is the Screen shot is of what I am getting and I am aiming to remove this pointless white bar which is hiding the text.
[The Screen Shot of the Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pwwb.jpg)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although in theory customizing the theme with no title bar should work, however in my case it didn't work. So I solved it by removing the following section from the activity_*class*.xml

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create custom theme eg. CustomTheme in styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

and in manifest.xml use

```
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the prompt response. I tried the above mentioned changes and still shows the bar :/.

Comment: I think there might be some other problem which I can't see. Should the activity (Used for Dialog) blank or empty ? .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```